# How to read and write music scores if I am a blind musician?

Tags: software

I am a fully blind person, now beginning to learn violin with Western classics.
I am presently preparing for Trinity grade 3  practical. I am just looking for a sheet music reader and writer software solution  to find out if such software availability will help me to create scores with my own ideas.
Can anybody suggest any resource?

Comment: Related: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/10649/resource-for-sheet-music-for-blind-musicians

Answer (score 5):

You do get braille music.

> Braille music is a Braille code that allows music to be notated using
>   Braille cells so music can be read by visually impaired musicians. The
>   Braille music system was originally developed by Louis Braille.
>
> Braille cell, 2 dots wide by 3 dots high Braille music uses the same
>   six-position Braille cell as literary braille. However braille music
>   assigns a separate meaning to each braille symbol or group of symbols
>   different from literary braille and has its own syntax and
>   abbreviations.
>
> Almost anything that can be written in print music notation can be
>   written in braille music notation. However, braille music notation is
>   an independent and well-developed system with its own conventions.
>
> The world's largest collection of braille music is located at the
>   National Library for the Blind in Stockport, UK.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wn2PE.gif)

[image]

[SOURCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille_music#Learning_Braille_music)

Comment: Blind musicians I have known have used this Braille system, but also learned to play by ear.

Comment: Braille scores can be difficult to come across, however, depending on where you are located, your local city or university library may be able to do an Inter-Library Loan (it could be called something else in other areas).  A blind student I knew was able to access a large collection through a network of University libraries in the US.